# Learning language by singing songs?

Tags: learning-methods, reference-request, self-learning, speaking

[Learn languages by memorizing rhymed poems](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2270/learn-languages-by-memorizing-rhymed-poems) is about pro/cons of using poems to learn a language.

What about using **songs**? Songs might use more modern language, avoiding the cons mentioned for poems.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earworm) suggest the earworm effect exists, and [earwormslearning.com](https://www.earwormslearning.com/) website sells a product (and has some science linked). But of course any science linked from a vendor website is suspect.

Is there any research about using songs to learn a language and developing the speaking skills? Songs do no have to be earworms.

I know from my personal experience, that Beatles helped me to learn English, and [AZLyrics.com](https://www.azlyrics.com/) has the lyrics for all the songs I ever wanted (I wanted mostly Beatles tho :-) so not sure about all other groups).

Possibly related: Can possibly songs help with learning [English stress-timed rhythm](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/how-can-one-learn-english-stress-timed-rhythm)? I can split it to separate question if it is separate enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is plenty of research on this topic. [*The Use of Music for Learning Languages: A Review* (Stansell)](http://writingthetrueself.com//pdfs/Jon_Stansell_The_Use_of_Music_for_Learning_Languages.pdf) asserts that *(emphasis mine)*:

> The researchers in this literature review show conclusively that music and language should
>   be studied together. Music‟s success is due, in part, to primal human abilities. Music codes
>   words with heavy emotional and contextual flags, evoking a realistic, meaningful, and cogent
>   environment, and enabling students to have positive attitudes, self-perceptions, and cultural
>   appreciation so they can actively process new stimuli and infer the rules of language. The
>   universal element of music can make the artificial classroom environment into a “real”
>   experience and make new information meaningful, bringing interest and order to a classroom.
>
> ...
>
> One area to focus upon would be the use of music for instruction in **grammar**. Whereas it
>   takes little preparation to u**tilize songs for active class involvement, phrase and vocabulary
>   acquisition, cultural appreciation, and pronunciation**, grammar is seldom considered an issue that
>   music can benefit.
>
> ...
>
> This author has developed a new curriculum for teaching the Czech language, which has
>   students learning simple sentences with books of family pictures, singing five-part canons with
>   **grammar concepts embedded in them, chanting the pronoun endings of prepositional phrases,rhythmically moving, listening to different instruments, listening and reading, and having
>   dialogue with native speakers**. This system, the Phrase-Exemplar-based Multisensory Method
>   (PEBMSM) has been used by language trainers, but is primarily intended to be a demonstration
>   of the possible uses of music in a language learning context.

*[Why Use Music in English Language Learning? A Survey of the
Literature](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ1076582.pdf) (Engh)* provides that *(emphasis mine)*:

> The **use of rhythm and rhyme to assist auditory recall** has also been studied, and the multimodal combination of
>   **rhythm, melody and rhyme along with linguistic prosody** appears to lead to greater retention (Graham, 1992;
>   Palmer & Kelly, 1992).
>
> ...
>
> Murphey (1989) provides potential evidence regarding why music effectively **assists in lexical and phrasal recall**
>   in noting the **resemblance of songs to conversational discourse** and suggests they are linguistically processed in a
>   similar manner.
>
> Music in the language classroom may also be utilized with
>   an **explicit vocabulary and grammar focus** (Richards, 1969; Saricoban & Metin, 2000) and used to reinforce
>   either **grammar or pronunciation points** (Allen & Vallette, 1977). **Pronunciation and phonology** are a natural use
>   of songs in the aid of second language acquisition (Schön et al, 2008), and Leith (1979) states:
>
> …there is probably not a better nor quicker way to teach **phonetics** than with songs. Phonetics instruction is one
>   good use to which songs can be put even in beginning classes (540).
>   The **repetitive nature of songs** makes them effective use for pronunciation drills (Bartle, 1962; Techmeier, 1969;
>   Shaw, 1970) and lastly, it is argued that songs contextually introduce supra-segmental features (Lems, 2001;
>   Wong and Perrachione, 2006), which aids in the learning of patterns for word identification.
>
> Overall, the results are clear in suggesting use of music and song in the language-learning classroom is both
>   supported theoretically by practicing teachers and grounded in the empirical literature as a benefit to increase
>   **linguistic, sociocultural and communicative competencies. From an educational standpoint, music and language
>   not only can, but should be studied together.**

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with any research, but I did teach Spanish using current popular songs in Spanish and used them as dictations.  I would print the lyrics and place a blank where some words were.  I would use this as a "warm-up" at the beginning of class, giving them the lyrics and playing the music.

Then we would discuss the song and what it said, applying and learning new vocabulary.  I had a good response to this and thought the students learned a lot about culture, vocabulary and building listening skills.

Answer (score 2):

Music is a very good way to learn languages. It teaches you a lot of vocab that you wouldn't see in a textbook.

It helps you to get a grasp of the way the language is spoken by native speakers.

I have used this method to learn quite a lot of German. I personally like their rap music as it is easier to distinguish the words and follow along with what they are saying.

Answer (score -2):

i used to teach excellerated learning and i used music singing and dancing as a punishment would make each class a game and then give students points it was a fun and fast way to learn!! but need at least a class of 3 for it to be effective